# Does natural units lead to weird outcomes?

Tags: relativity

Relativistic energy and momentum relation is

$E^2 = p^2c^2 + m^2c^4$

if we choose natural units, that is, $\hbar = 1$ (which implies, $h=2\pi$, because $\hbar = \frac{h}{2\pi}$) and $c=1$, above equation becomes

$E^2 = p^2 + m^2$

Now, if I substitue $E=\frac{hc}{\lambda}= \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$ and $p=\frac{h}{\lambda} = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda}$, the equation becomes

$ \Big(\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\Big)^2 = \Big(\frac{2\pi}{\lambda}\Big)^2 +m^2$

which gives

$m^2=0$

I am sure, I am doing some very dumb mistake, but I am unable to figure it out. Can someone guide me?

Edit: removed the mistake after Jacob's comment.

Comment: $m^2=0$ only has $m=0$ as a solution. The issue is that $E=\frac{hc}{\lambda}$ is only true of massless particles (eg photons). In general you might have $E=\hbar \omega$ with a more complicated dispersion than just $\omega = c k $.

Comment: Also, as a side note: this has nothing to do with natural units since in SI your final equation would read the same.

Comment: @jacob1729 I got the mistake, it is a silly one. Will modify the question. Thanks.

Comment: @jacob1729 Thanks. Understood the mistake of mixing the concepts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even using SI units, the pair of equations
$$E = \frac{hc}{\lambda}$$
and
$$p = \frac{h}{\lambda}$$
together mean that $E = pc$, which is true only for massless particles.  By starting from these equations, you are making the tacit assumption that $m=0$, so ending up with $m=0$ at the end should not be surprising.